# How to align the date

Tags: tidyverse

There is `current_dataframe` ，how to align the `start_day` `end_day` and keep the `date_gap` not change (Is avaiable package or function for this)? Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)
current_dataframe <- data.frame(start_day=c('2022/1/19','2022/2/19','2022/4/19'),
           end_day=c('2022/1/25','2022/2/20','2022/4/24'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `lubridate` package to work with dates.  Use `ymd` to convert the character string into a date format.  Then `floor_date` can give you the first day of the month (it can do other units too).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

current_dataframe <- data.frame(start_day=c('2022/1/19','2022/2/19','2022/4/19'),
                                end_day=c('2022/1/25','2022/2/20','2022/4/24'))

current_dataframe %>% 
    mutate(across(c(start_day, end_day), ymd),
           days_gap = end_day - start_day,
           start_day = floor_date(start_day, "month"),
           end_day = start_day + days_gap)
```